# Plotly moveable/draggable legends, python

Tags: python, plotly

Is it possible to make the plotly legends draggable? Currently I have my legend positioned outside the graph. I want to move it inside the graph, which is covered in the documentation, but I want to be able to make it draggable.

Answer (score 0):

There is no direct way to drag the legend on a Plotly chart as far as I know.

You could find a workround by creating your legend in a HTML canvas and binding the onclick() function for each legend item to the [Plotly PostMessage API](https://github.com/plotly/postMessage-API) restyle task.

There's a live example of the PostMessage API [here](http://blog.hefce.ac.uk/2016/08/25/what-happens-if-you-graduate-in-a-recession/) which you should be able to hack apart. Let me know how you get on, this sounds interesting!

Answer (score 0):

You can set `"editable": True` in the plot config.

https://github.com/plotly/plotly.js/blob/master/src/plot_api/plot_config.js#L46-L54